# cat /proc/mtd No such file or directory

Tags: rom-flashing

I am trying to follow these [directions](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images) and I get stopped on the first step:

```
# cat /proc/mtd
/proc/mtd: No such file or directory
```

Help?

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't exist on your device.  It doesn't on my Vibrant either, though I can get somewhat similar info via `cat /proc/partitions`.

Comment: Any idea how I figure out which ones are the boot and recovery images?

Comment: @TestPlanManagement.com Not sure. The output of `mount` shows me where `/system` and `/cache` are (etc) but nothing about boot and recovery.

Answer (score 2):

Some (newer?) phones do not use `/dev/mtd*` devices.

Instead, you must look for your device file in the `/dev/block/platform/*/by-name` directory (`*` is expanded to the usually single subdirectory below `platform/`). While the exact name varies depending on the device, it should remain something meaningful (like `boot`, or `LNX` as an acronym for "Linux", etc.).

You should end-up with a path similar to `/dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/LNX` that you will then be able to use to pull the `boot.img` file (FYI I cover this more deeply in my answer to [this other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69954/107603)).