# How to unpack and edit boot.img for ROM porting?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

I recently downloaded [this ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2480246) for my Allview P5 (Allview P5 is the equivalent of Gionee GN700W/FLY IQ441/QMobile Noir A8). It`s called Primonex ROM and is made for the Gionee version of the phone.

- Firstly, I tried to install it as it is but it got stuck at the boot screen.
- After some research I found out that it could be a problem with the `boot.img` file and I don't know how to extract or edit it...

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: If you're on a Linux kernel, you could use abootimg

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64628/how-to-extract-boot-img

Answer (score 16):

## Tools selection

The method I present here relies on CyanogenMod's Android source code.

While Google's AOSP only provides the tool to *build* the `boot.img` file, CyanogenMod also adds the `unpackbootimg` tool allowing you to *unpack* it. This tool does not seem specifically designed for CyanogenMod in any way, so most chances are that it will work for other ROMs as well.

There are, however, a relatively large number of alternatives to unpack the `boot.img` file which all work more-or-less the same.

Basically, such unpack tool will extract the content of the `boot.img` file and display a set of parameters you will have to pass to Google's `mkbootimg` tool to build a file whose configuration (mainly kernel parameters and memory addresses) will match the original one.

Here are a few examples, I did not test them personally so cannot recommend any and I present them only for reference purposes:

- A few are open source or script based:

  - [The Android Kitchen](https://github.com/dsixda/Android-Kitchen/) was apparently meant to be some kind of Swiss army knife for Android developers. The original author officially stopped maintaining the project, a few other users forked it like [javilonas](https://github.com/javilonas/Android-Kitchen) or [cmotc](https://github.com/cmotc/Android-Kitchen).
  - [szym](https://github.com/szym/unbootimg) targets easiness by adding shell script wrappers to its toolset to make the complete unpacking and repacking process more straightforward.
  - [osm0sis](https://github.com/osm0sis/mkbootimg) proposes a fork of CyanogenMod's tools *"forked and updated"* according to the project's own description. This project seems indeed still maintained which is not very common in this area, however the actual advantage over CyanogenMod's original tools remains unclear to me.
- Some are free closed source proprietary binaries:

  - [Kuisma's `unmkbootimg`](http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Unmkbootimg) appears pretty often in help forums and seems to do a good job in helping to handle odd cases, outputting "human readable" English recommendation when some modification are required in `mkbootimg` source code and displaying the exact command-line to use to rebuild the image.
  - [Xiaolu's `mkbootimg_tools`](https://github.com/xiaolu/mkbootimg_tools) seems also mentioned quite often and allows to unpack and repack `boot.img` and the device tree file `dt.img`. Don't be fooled by the fact it is hosted on GitHub: it *is* a closed source proprietary binary and only compiled binaries are available on their repository (actually I'm even wondering about the exact interest of using a source-code repository to store binary blobs, but different people, different minds...).
  - [CNexus](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2319018) on the XDA forum provides an archive with a selection of tools.
  - [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65316/53965) in Unix.SE recommends [some tools](http://android-serialport-api.googlecode.com/files/android_bootimg_tools.tar.gz) from the now seemingly defunct Android Serial Port project. The file names, however, lead me to think these should be old prebuilt versions of CyanogenMod's tools (the project being closed, there is neither documentation nor support).

All these tools (and others you may find with any search engine) should work the same way, but some may work better than others in handling some particular edge-case you may face with your own device. Most of them however, at least in the open source arena, do not seem regularly maintained, so the best bet in my opinion to have working, maintained and documented tools is to go with CyanogenMod's ones.

Some manufacturers produce ROMs which are more or less far from AOSP standard (unusual addresses, headers, file format, etc.). If the standard procedure below does not work, maybe one of these alternative software may do the trick. Otherwise, you will have to check for issues specific to your device: some seem to need a specific procedure or even specific tools (confer [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58825/107603) related to MediaTek devices, for instance).

## Tools installation

Compiling CyanogenMod toolset for `boot.img` packing and unpacking is quite straightforward.

- If you already have installed the complete Android source code tree (you can check [my other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154947/107603) to get more information about this), go in `system/core/mkbootimg/` directory (as a reminder, Google's AOSP source code only provide the tool to build the `boot.img` file, they do *not* provide any unpacking tool),
- If you haven't and don't need this for any other purpose, an easier and quicker solution is to only clone CyanogenMod's *android_system_core* repository:

  ```
    git clone https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_system_core.git
    cd android_system_core/mkbootimg/
  ```

Once in the right directory, compile and install:

```
gcc -o ./mkbootimg -I ../include ../libmincrypt/*.c ./mkbootimg.c
gcc -o ./unpackbootimg -I ../include ../libmincrypt/*.c ./unpackbootimg.c
sudo cp ./mkbootimg ./unpackbootimg /usr/bin/
```

Note that Google is replacing the C `mkbootimg` with [a Python version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/ad6ec0c7fe8b5cd80dff619f1d3b6067db85110a), so in future versions no compilation may be needed anymore for this command.

You will also need to install Android tools on your computer to let it communicate with your phone. You will need `adb` (Android Debug Bridge, a shell utility allowing to communicate with Android's debug subsystem), `adbd` (the related daemon) and `fastboot` (a shell utility allowing to communicate with your phone's bootloader system).

Your favorite Linux distribution may provide them in a single or separate packages, but usually they are always called "android-tools":

- Debian / Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install android-tools-{adb,adbd,fastboot}`
- Fedora / CentOS: `sudo yum install android-tools`
- openSUSE: `sudo zypper install android-tools`

## Fetch the `boot.img` file

Extract the boot.img either from ROM .zip file or directly from the device:

- From the stock ROM .zip file: some applications like SuperSU may modify the boot.img directly on the device, replacing it with the stock one would break such applications.
- Directly from the device: some people report read issue leading to corrupted `boot.img`. IMO, these issues are most likely linked to the use of poor USB cables or USB hub and can be simply avoided by using good quality cables connecting directly the phone to the computer. You also need the ability to run ADB in root mode (depending on the ROM used, this may be trivial or not).

The first method is very obvious: extract the .zip file with any ZIP software, the `boot.img` file should be right there at the root of the archive.

For the second method, you will first have to determine the (sadly device-specific) path to the storage device where `boot.img`'s content can be retrieved. I know two methods for this:

- `ls /dev/block/platform/*/by-name/` (where `*` covers yet another device-specific folder name, chances are it is the only directory below `platform/`), the exact name to search is also platform dependent but makes usual sense (some examples: `boot`, `LNX` (acronym for "Linux")). The files in this directory are actually symbolic links and some people bother to manually go to the target, but I recommend sticking with the higher level name based path which, while longer, remains less error prone. So you will end-up with a path like `/dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/LNX`.
- On some (older?) devices, the right device could be found by investigating the output of `cat /proc/mtd`. If you see the device `mtd2` associated to the `"boot"` label, then you will use the path `/dev/mtd2`.

Now:

- From the phone's developer menu:

  - Enable debugging on your phone,
  - Allow root access to ADB (this step applies to phones running CynogenMod, other devices may require some potentially more complex procedure),
- Connect it to your computer (and from there to the VM guest if you are running Android tools from within a virtual machine).

If this is not already done, I recommend to manually start the ADB server on the computer's side, this will allow you to directly validate the RSA key on device's side without affecting the behavior of the following ADB commands:

```
adb start-server
```

Then switch ADB in root mode:

```
adb root
```

Finally, you should be able to directly extract the `boot.img` file from the device using such command (the source and destination path and names are given as examples, adapt them to your needs and preferences):

```
adb pull /dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/LNX ./boot.img
```

The command will copy the whole partition, both used and free space, so don't be surprised that the resulting `boot.img` file will be larger than the original `boot.img` file coming with the stock ROM .zip file, the content itself remains similar.

Once the transfer is finished, disconnect the phone and don't forget to disable both debugging and root access from the developer menu.

## Unpack the original `boot.img` file

Unpack the `boot.img` file itself using the command compiled previously:

```
unpackbootimg -i ./boot.img
```

This will output several information essential to let you rebuild a new `boot.img` with the correct structure with respect to the stock `boot.img`. However, don't rush on your notepad since CyanogenMod's `upackbootimg` also saves the very same information in several files we will use later on.

This command generates several files with particular suffixes added to the input file's name:

- `*-second`: This is the second-stage bootloader, optional and rarely used on end-user phones. If this file is empty (the most common case), then the phone's bootloader will directly call the Linux kernel.
- `*-zImage`: This is the Linux kernel.
- `*-ramdisk.gz` or `*-ramdisk.lz4`: the RAM disk used to populate the device's root directory. The extension differs depending on the compression algorithm used.
- `*-dt`: The device tree, populating `/dev`.
- The rest are small files each storing one of the values displayed in `unpackbootimg` output. These values define the command-line parameter to pass to the Linux kernel and the addresses where the bootloader will have to load each object at boot time.

Most often, one unpacks the `boot.img` to be able to edit the content of the phone's root directory. As seen above, this content is stored in the `*-ramdisk.gz` or `*-ramdisk.lz4` file and it can be extracted using the commands below:

```
mkdir ./ramdisk
cd ./ramdisk/
gzip -dc ../boot.img-ramdisk.gz | cpio -imd
```

For an LZ4 compressed RAM disk, replace the last step with `lz4 -d ../boot.img-ramdisk.lz4 | cpio -imd`.

You are now free to do the modification you want before proceeding. However, it could be worth to follow the full unpack - repack - boot procedure once without changing anything to ensure that your tools are working as expected. Otherwise, in case of an issue, you will not be certain if the cause is your modification or some incompatibility (see my remarks at the beginning about some manufacturers requiring non-standard procedures or tools).

## Rebuild to get the new `new-boot.img` file

CyanogenMod ROM building process relies on an internal tool, `mkbootfs`, to produce the `boot.img` file (this happens in [build/tools/releasetools/common.py](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_build/blob/cm-13.0/tools/releasetools/common.py)). However, the steps to build this tool seems uselessly complex to me, whereas using the system-provided `cpio` seems to work just as fine. The main difference between the two, as per my understanding after a (very) quick check in `mkbootfs` souce code, seems to be that the latter applies some sanity measures by not including dotted files and the `/root` directory in the resulting archive while the `cpio`-based procedure below will just blindly put the whole selected directory tree in the archive.

Conclusion: unnecessarily complex to compile with very few advantages, so let's stick on system provided tools!

Begin by creating the new RAM disk, from the `ramdisk` directory created above, type:

```
find . ! -name . | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o -H newc -R root:root | gzip > ../new-boot.img-ramdisk.gz
```

Or, if you need to generate an LZ4 archive:

```
find . ! -name . | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o -H newc -R root:root | lz4 > ../new-boot.img-ramdisk.lz4
```

The goal here is to create a new RAM disk file with properties as close as possible to the original one (for instance, setting the owner seems often missing in the procedures shared in forums and blogs, however this was required on my device).

Go now in the parent directory to generate the `new-boot.img` file itself.

```
cd ..
```

As seen above, CyanogenMod's `unpackbootimg` command generates a file matching each parameter expected by `mkbootimg`. Therefore, all you have to do is issue a `mkbootimg -h` to get a listing of all parameters, then set each one of them to the appropriate value using the matching file. Note that some parameters expect a file path while others expect to receive the content of the file as value. See an example of resulting command below:

```
mkbootimg                                           \
--kernel ./boot.img-zImage                          \
--ramdisk ./new-boot.img-ramdisk.gz                 \
--second ./boot.img-second                          \
--cmdline "$(cat ./boot.img-cmdline)"               \
--base "$(cat ./boot.img-base)"                     \
--pagesize "$(cat ./boot.img-pagesize)"             \
--dt ./boot.img-dt                                  \
--ramdisk_offset "$(cat ./boot.img-ramdisk_offset)" \
--second_offset "$(cat ./boot.img-second_offset)"   \
--tags_offset "$(cat ./boot.img-tags_offset)"       \
--output ./new-boot.img
```

Only two parameters are not set here:

- `--board`: As per my understanding, this is just an informative field allowing to insert a model name in the resulting image.
- `--id`: This one does not expect any value, it just prints out a unique identifier after the image has been built (combining a timestamp and a checksum).

## Flash the `new-boot.img` file onto the device

- Start the device in fastboot mode (aka bootloader mode, usually by holding power and volume up buttons).
- Connect the USB cable.
- Check that the device is correctly detected:

  ```
    sudo fastboot devices
  ```
- Try to boot using the new ROM (without flashing it yet, so in case of issue you just have to restart the phone to get it back on trails, replace the `./new-boot.img` file name with your own):

  ```
    sudo fastboot boot ./new-boot.img
  ```
- If the phone works successfully with the new boot image, then go back in fastboot mode and flash it permanently:

  ```
    sudo fastboot flash boot ./new-boot.img
    sudo fastboot reboot
  ```

## Conclusion

This procedure may seem daunting at first, but once you get it, you will see it is actually not.

The "daunting" aspect comes from the fact that there is not a single "Android system": a lot of manufacturers and ROM providers make changes which can range from a subtle path difference to a completely non-standard environment.

What you have to do is determine your particular device's posture, and then what are the few commands which are appropriate in your case. Once you get them, you can stick to them and even easily script them if you need them often.

I voluntarily went into relatively low-level details sometimes because it will make you troubleshooting your issues more easily. Would you use some "easier" opaque utility to build and flash your new `boot.img` file and see that your device cannot start with it, it would be harder for you to determine which step went wrong. Here, at each step, you will be able to compare the data you are manipulating with the data coming from the original `boot.img` file or the data as seen on the phone, or try for instance to rebuild the `boot.img` file with either the original or the newly generated RAM disk file to check if that makes any difference (this allows you to pinpoint if the issue comes from the `boot.img` or the RAM disk file generation procedure).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Android Kitchen.](https://github.com/dsixda/Android-Kitchen/) There is an option to unpack/repack boot.img there, under `Advanced options`.

Comment: Sadly the original author has officially stopped to maintain the Android Kitchen: "[This project is retired as of 2013, as I have become overwhelmed with the number of devices to support, the demand, bad health, and the constant requests for help](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=5626292#post5626292)". A few forks have been made though (I give some links in my answer), but I do not know how much they are supported (I did not find any obvious public way to raise issues or request an evolution for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to edit boot.img on some no-name mediatek phone only [Android boot image editor](https://github.com/cfig/Android_boot_image_editor) worked perfectly. It's simple and easy to use. Other tools are either not maintained anymore, or produced invalid boot image.