# Where does the top-level structure come from?

Tags: file-system

Most Android devices that I am aware of programmed to mount the system partition at `/system`. All partitions get mounted at folders underneath `/`. Looking at my device's `/proc/mounts` shows that `rootfs`, some kind of special filesystem is mounted at `/`, unlike on desktop versions of Linux that mount something like `/dev/sda1` at `/`. Besides folders, there are also important files like `init` directly under `/`. Where do these files and folders come from?

Comment: Those files and folder structure are created by using the content of the ramdisk contained in the boot.img. That's why any modifications you perform on a file located at **/** gets rolled back on reboot.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman while being short, that's basically the answer to this question. Enhance it a little (what is a boot image etc), and it should be pretty fine :) Pointer to link to: [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575)

Comment: @Izzy I'm sorry, honorable colleague, but I guess that the privilege of publishing the answer will be yours. While being happy that my answer might address the question, I have no time to invest in mining the necessary info about ramdisks and boot.img content, since I've been notified that I've to review some critiques I made. Might you take the pleasure of answering in my stead?

Comment: Near duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/130348/218526

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Doing this answer on behalf of [Death Mask Salesman](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/152843/death-mask-salesman) who currently lacks the time:</sup>

To get a general idea of how the boot process on Android works, please take a look at [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29706/16575) Don't get confused of the term "Dalvik" there: for Android 5+ simply replace it by "ART", the process is the same.

Step 3 is explained there as *[The] Linux kernel [takes control], which will, together with the init process, initialize the base system, e.g. caches, file systems, etc.* This is where file systems are set up. Details on those can be found e.g. in [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575): Basically, there are multiple partitions on the device where e.g. the OS components are stored (`/system`), the user data go to (`/data`) then the SD cards, etc; then there are "virtual file systems" like `/proc` and `/dev`.

The root file system (`/`) is something special, and comes from a so called "initial RAM disk" ([Initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd)), which is loaded from a file (a so called [Boot image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_image)). Hence on each boot, the root file system is "generated" freshly from that file – replacing all changes you've made to it prior that boot. There are several boot scripts executed to perform this job (usually it's the `init.rc` you see in the root folder – but depending on the device, it could be other/additional scripts), e.g. creating additional "directories and mounts".

Additional details can be found behind the following links:

- [Android Booting](http://elinux.org/Android_Booting)
- [init/readme.txt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/readme.txt)
- [Android's Init](http://cecs.wright.edu/~pmateti/Courses/4900/Lectures/Internals/Embedded-Android-228-247-pm.pdf) (PDF)