# Recompile kernel: no errors but it doesn't work

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, boot, kernel

I'm a beginner, and at the moment I'm trying just to repack original boot image. I've discovered that boot partition is on the "/dev/block/mmcblk0p7", so I pulled it with `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p7 original_boot.img`
Then with tools from https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2319018 I've unpacked original boot and then recompiled it. But then my image don't boot. Flashing it with TWRP caused bootloop. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Kinda close to off topic but I do not think so. My reasoning is because it has to do with repacking a boot image and not the compilation of the kernel. Also, I found a possible duplicate with this https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69954/how-to-unpack-and-edit-boot-img-for-rom-porting check the compression also. How arw you repacking the boot.img?

Comment: @BoLawson I don't think its a duplicate. First, I've `unpack original_boot.img` then used the command which  Boot.img tools provided when unpacked: `mkbootimg --kernel zImage --ramdisk initramfs.cpio.gz --base 0x4dffff00 --cmdline 'bootopt=64S3,32N2,64N2' --board '1450664547' -o new_boot.img`

Comment: Use [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775)

Comment: @IrfanLatif same result